# Why are initializer lists not available when changing the allocator of std::vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-alignment, initializer-list, eigen3

In my project I changed the used point type from `Eigen::Vector2f` to `Eigen::Vector2d` and ran into the alignment problem.

Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>

int main()
{
    std::vector<Eigen::Vector2d> points = { {0,0}, {0,1} };
}
```

I'm getting the following run time error:

```
eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:78: Eigen::internal::plain_array<double, 2, 0, 16>::plain_array() [T = double, Size = 2, MatrixOrArrayOptions = 0, Alignment = 16]: Assertion `(reinterpret_cast<size_t>(array) & 0xf) == 0 && "this assertion is explained here: " "http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html" " **** READ THIS WEB PAGE !!! ****"' failed.
```

As the assert-message suggested, I read about the required [alignment of Fixed-size vectorizable Eigen objects](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicUnalignedArrayAssert.html). And also the subsection about [STL Containers](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TopicStlContainers.html). And it seems like I have two options:

1. use the `Eigen::aligned_allocator`
2. or use the `EIGEN_DEFINE_STL_VECTOR_SPECIALIZATION` macro.

Both attempts do not compile (tested with GCC 4.8.3 and Clang 3.5) because the compiler is not able to properly convert the initializer list.

Here the altered code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <Eigen/Eigen>
#include <Eigen/StdVector>
// EIGEN_DEFINE_STL_VECTOR_SPECIALIZATION(Eigen::Vector2d)

int main()
{
    std::vector<Eigen::Vector2d, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Vector2d>> points = { {0,0}, {0,1} };
    // std::vector<Eigen::Vector2d> points = { {0,0}, {0,1} };
}
```

GCC error output:

```
error: could not convert ‘{{0, 0}, {0, 1}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1>, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double, 2, 1> > >’
```

So I'm wondering:

- Why are initializer lists not available when changing the allocator of the `std::vector`?

  - Is this because of alignment?
  - Can I somehow align the initializer list?
- Why is the specialization version failing?

  - Are these lacking the initializer list feature?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After studying the `Eigen/StdVector` include file (to be precise it is in [`Eigen/src/StlSupport/StdVector.h` line 68 of version 3.2.1](https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/src/e951c74f43bab298849438ac01b94de201b1dd75/Eigen/src/StlSupport/StdVector.h?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#StdVector.h-68)), it seems that the problem originates from a partial template specialization of the `std::vector` within this header file. This partial template specialization replaces the STL `vector` as soon as you use `Eigen::aligned_allocator` as allocator. And this specialization seems to lack the C++11 features.

**In detail why this specialization is necessary apart from replacing the allocator:**
Before C++11 the [resize function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) of the `std::vector` could take an additional parameter by value to initialize newly created elements. [According to the Eigen3 Documentation](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicStlContainers.html) passing a parameter by value discards any alignment modifiers and cannot be used with fixed-size vectorizable Eigen objects (see SIMD).

**Edit:**
After some more testing I realized that the C++11 implementation of the `std::vector` does not have the above stated issue. So to resolve the alignment problem you **only** need to fill in the `Eigen::aligned_allocator`. But **do not** include `Eigen/StdVector`. Including this file will prevent you from using the C++11 implementation of `std::vector` since this header defines a partial specialization with `Eigen::aligned_allocator` as allocator.